# Как загрузить фотографию из буфера обмена?

Tags: php, javascript

Передо мной поставили задачу: при помощи <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> вставить на сайте картинку и потом сохранить ее.

Как это можно сделать?

Какой тип input`а при этом использовать?

Comment: Не буду писать ответ, но может помочь отвечающему: http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/IoJbg

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, полноценно и кроссбраузерно - никак. Кросс-браузерность в известных решениях этой проблемы частично решала технология Flash. Изучить методы и посмотреть поддержку работы с `window.clipboardData` [здесь](http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboardData)

Рекомендую вам воспользоваться функциями dragAndDrop